# jQuery Mobile blinking at page transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing iPad app using jquery mobile 1.0 and cordova-1.6.0. My application works fine.

When I use jquery mobile 1.1 ,  page is blinking at page transition. 
What is the reason for this?

---

Is it jQuery mobile 1.1 bug?

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

This is jQuery mobile bug, which has been fixed in their latest jQuery mobile version(1.1.1). Please check out http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/07/12/jqm-1-1-1/

Comment: Which browser you are using? This problem getting mainly for android default browser. In android chrome browser it is working perfect. With the same version in iPad it is very smooth for me.